# Collect rows in one Google sheet matching a string of characters in a column of another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a google sheet (probably similar formula with excel) with two sheets, and I want to have one sheet 'detect' if a cell of a row has a certain string of characters (e.g., it starts with 'blood sample') and collect the rows that match that string.

So the sheet 'Trial' looks like this

```
A|B
1|3
2|2
3|5
1|4
2|4
2|5
1|5
1|3
```

From the two columns `A` and `B` above, how do you filter to another sheet so that if `A = 1`, it will display the corresponding value of `B` (and a few other columns) WITHOUT leaving empty rows in between? So the final result should look like this

```
A|B
1|3
1|4
1|5
1|3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query formula like:

```
=QUERY('Sheet 01'!A1:B,"where A=1 and A is not null")
```

*(please adjust ranges to your needs)*

You can also read more about [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

---

### EDIT

Please keep in mind that the example in your question *("So the sheet 'Trial' looks like this... till the end")* does NOT match your first paragraph.

If you are really looking for an answer for

> ...if a cell of a row has a certain string of characters (e.g., it starts with 'blood sample') and collect the rows that match that string.

use the following query

```
=query('Sheet 01'!A1:B,"where A starts with 'blood sample' and A is not null")
```

[image]